# Image upload to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have the following to add an image in the wordpress post:

```
<?php
    global $current_user;

    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
            $title =  $_POST['title'];
                } else {
                  echo 'Please enter a title';
                }
            if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
                $description = $_POST['description'];
                } else {
                    echo 'Please enter the content';
                }
            $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
            $custom_field_1 = $_POST['custom_1'];
            $custom_field_2 = $_POST['custom_2']; 
            $post = array(
                    'post_title'    => $title,
                    'post_content'  => $description,
                    'post_category' => $_POST['cat'],  
                    'tags_input'    => $tags,                                   
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',           
                    'post_type' => $_POST['post_type'] 
                );

                    $pid = wp_insert_post($post);
                    add_post_meta($pid, 'rh_content', $custom_field_1, true);
                            add_post_meta($pid, 'rh_item', $custom_field_2, true);  

            if ($_FILES) {
                    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
                                                        }
                            }                               
                            wp_redirect( home_url() );                                      
                        }                           
                        do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
                    ?>
```

So, it allows an image to be uploaded which can be shown by `get_the_post_thumbnail`.

```
 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <div class="rhmi_thumb">                        
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'rh_site') ?>
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

However, even without the image uploaded (ie. there is no thumbnail), it still shows `class="rhmi_thumb"`. So, I am guessing that the whether an image is uploaded or not, the post thinks that there is a thumbnail.

What modification should be made in the post upload form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading image into page/post you have to use [wp_insert_attachment()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment). I have added the link of wordpress site from there you can get the example that how you can implement that. Thanks!